# Why No "Integration Service Project" binding to "Server Explorer"?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, ssis

When I create a SSIS package in BIDS (VS 2008), it has no integration with the "server explorer" panel.  For example, I can't:

- drag and drop a (server explorer) database onto the "Data Sources" folder of the project.
- drag and drop a (server explorer) database onto the "Bulk Insert Task" for the destination connection.
- select a (server explorer) database from a drop down on the properties of one of the SSIS tasks.

In short, "server explorer" might as well not exist when working in an "integration service project".  That is quite strange, because all the above "features" are so obvious.  Why does the IDE not offer these actions / features?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you're not doing anything wrong and no one knows exactly why those features are not available except Microsoft. As a complete guess, the server explorer represents physical databases but it's a key principle of SSIS that physical connections are always abstracted away behind logical connection managers, so you should be concerned mainly with data sources and/or connection managers.

But that's not a great explanation because obviously you do need to deal with physical data sources in order to design packages and dragging a database from server explorer to create a data source or connection manager could be convenient, as you suggest.

It's also the case that SSMS and BIDS have various limitations compared to the 'normal' Visual Studio experience you get for other project types. You might find  the [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/documentation) tool useful for improving the functionality, and you can use the [Connect](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/sqlserver/) site to give feedback to Microsoft on possible enhancements.

Comment: It is quiet obvious that the SSIS development team did not talk to the Visual Studio dev team.